# puma new fork-worker option, relation to preload_app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, puma

Puma5 has a new fork_worker option.

https://github.com/puma/puma/blob/master/5.0-Upgrade.md
https://github.com/puma/puma/blob/master/docs/fork_worker.md

The docs mention:

> Similar to the preload_app! option, the fork_worker option allows your application to be initialized only once for copy-on-write memory savings, and it has two additional advantages...

I'm confused if this means it's an *alternative* to `preload_app!`, or if it's meant to be used in conjunction with `preload_app!`.

If I already was using `preload_app!`, and want to try the new experimental `fork_worker` option, should I have both `preload_app!` and `fork_worker` in my puma config file, does that make sense? Or it should it be one or the other but not both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check the [Limitations](https://github.com/puma/puma/blob/master/docs/fork_worker.md#limitations), you will read the following:

> Not compatible with the preload_app! option

Interestingly enough, the [commit](https://github.com/puma/puma/blame/master/docs/fork_worker.md#L27) was added seven days after you asked the question!

Although this has been answered on the doc itself and by now you've probably found out yourself, it feels better to see the question answered here also.

Comment: thanks! what happens if you configure both to be on though?

Comment: Haven't tried that myself @jrochkind - but the guys who are responsible for the description of the options _suggest_ that its not compatible: The link provided points you to [#2468](https://github.com/puma/puma/pull/2468) and then you can click on [#2466](https://github.com/puma/puma/issues/2466). The [2nd](https://github.com/puma/puma/issues/2466#issuecomment-718271840) reply says that ii simply doesn't work.